# How can we read files from samba server in mule?

Tags: mule, samba, mule-component

I want to read some files from samba server, it looks like smb protocol is not one of the supported protocols by mule components like ftp, sftp etc.. So can anyone share some ideas including example implementation for doing this? Let us assume we want to read a csv file and save it to payload so that it can be used to pass to weave transform component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you would mount the share via the operating system and then start the Mule Runtime process in the context of a user/grp that has the proper permissions to rw.

Comment: Yes, you would simply use the File connector.